# is it necessary to use after in the case below?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-structure

Is it correct to say: It is just five o'clock when the time is 5:03 
OR It is correct to say: It is just after five o'clock ??!
is AFTER necessary??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is really a language question; it's a precision question.

In many situations, a certain level of imprecision is quite acceptable:

> "The party's at seven, should we start getting ready?"
>
> "Oh, no, it's only five o'clock."

This is fine anywhere between around 4:55 and 5:05 or so - it's entirely subjective.

> "Oh no, am I late? What time is it?"
>
> "It's just after five o'clock."

This is also fine giving an approximation of the time.

> "All right, I'm calling it. Time of death?"
>
> "Five-oh-three, doctor."

This is a situation where you really want the precision.

In general, in most situations you don't need to state the exact time. There are a lot of different ways to say the same time in English, and not much consensus about which is 'correct'. 5:15 can be said as:

Five-fifteen;

A quarter past five;

A quarter after five;

A quarter of five;

Seventeen-Fifteen;

...among others. All are correct, and generally a matter of personal preference or, in some cases, organisation policy.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct, but the difference is in the semantics.

The former means that the time has **just reached** five o'clock, or that the time is **only** five o'clock.

The latter means that it is a **small amount of time after** five o'clock.

Both may be valid in your situation depending on context, though I get the feeling you mean the latter.